# How can I retry failed end to end tests in Detox using Mocha?

Tags: react-native, mocha.js, detox

I have a [flaky end-to-end test](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Flakiness.md) that uses [Detox](https://github.com/wix/Detox) and [Mocha](https://mochajs.org).

The Mocha test runner allows for [multiple retries](https://mochajs.org/#retry-tests). I tried using the recommended Mocha syntax:

```
// auth.spec.js
describe('App authentication', () => {

  this.retries(2);

  it('should have a login screen', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('LoginScreenView'))).toBeVisible();
  });

});
```

However, it appears `this` is an empty object (`{}`) and does not have a `retries` function when running Detox with Mocha as the test runner.

It generates the following error:

```
node_modules/.bin/mocha __e2e__ --opts __e2e__/config/mocha.opts --

configuration ios.sim.debug      --grep :android: --invert     --artifacts-location "__e2e__/artifacts/ios.sim.debug.2018-10-17 22-51-12Z" 
/<path>/__e2e__/auth.spec.js:10
  this.retries(2);
       ^

TypeError: this.retries is not a function
    at Suite.describe (/<path>/__e2e__/auth.spec.js:4:8)
    at Object.create (/<path>/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:112:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/<path>/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:40:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/<path>/__e2e__/auth.spec.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /<path>/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:250:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/<path>/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:247:14)
    at Mocha.run (/<path>/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:576:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/<path>/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:637:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
child_process.js:644
    throw err;
    ^
```

Is there a way to automatically retry failed tests in Detox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in mocha can't work with arrow function, so must change it into ordinary one

```
// auth.spec.js
describe('App authentication', function () { // change it

  this.retries(2);
```

It is not recommended best practice to use in Mocha

Ref:
https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions

Hope it helps